# Running PVC water pipe to 2nd floor balcony

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, outdoor

I want to run a simple water line outside from my faucet to my 2nd floor balcony so I can easily water my plants. It’s not a very long distance, but I’m wondering what my best options are. Here are photos of where it would run:

[image]

[image]

My plan was to just run a 3/4” or 1/2” PVC pipe down from the faucet to the top of the slab, then run it along the house to the water drainage duct. From there, up alongside then behind the duct (I estimate I can fit 1/2” or 3/4” pipe between the duct and the house), then across to the top of the balcony railing, where I would terminate it with a standard hose male adapter so I could screw in a small garden hose.

Any considerations I should keep in mind? I don’t want to over complicate this, but my primary objectives are to keep the pipe as hidden as possible (hence, I plan to order dark gray pipe and connectors if possible) as well as obviously having at least a little bit of water pressure to water plants.

Comment: Do you get freezing temperatures in the winter?  Would need a drain at lowest point if you do, looks like bend at the 70 and 17 inch lines.

Comment: I don’t think it ever freezes? But good to know. I’ll definitely consider that.

Comment: Since this is at the top of the list again today. A drawback to PVC is that it does tend to degrade in UV. Painting it would help protect it, and there are UV resistant PVCs that you could purchase. Of course, you'd probably want to paint it anyway so that you have a nice looking grey line, instead of an ugly white or yellowish (CPVC is designed for pressure and is an ugly yellow color) running along the outside of the house.

Answer (score 3):

**I would use a hose.**

It is outside, after all!  The natural habitat of hoses.  Attach it to the faucet.  Run the hose up behind the downspout.  Put a hook or stay where you want it to turn horizontal and come over to the porch.  It needs to hold the weight of the hose when full of water so make it substantial.  Maybe a pipe clamp on the hose where it turns so there is a solid transition.  Then bring it over to the porch and have a hook to hang the hose gun on.

The good thing about this: all you need is the hooks and a hose.  You can put it up in 10 minutes.  If you change your mind or want to do something different it all comes down easily and you have a fine hose you can use for washing the car.

Comment: Hm yeah I had considered this. Maybe I’ll look into that instead of a semi-permanent PVC setup. I guess I’d have to make sure the hose was particularly rigid so a 90° bend won’t create a kink. Thanks for the suggestion though. I may give this a go and report back!

Comment: You could use a threaded metal elbow piece for the 90 degree bend at deck level.  It would mean 2 short hoses or one that you cut and put new threads on for before and after the elbow.  But the elbow would be solid and very suitable for hanging on the hook.

Comment: Good idea! I’ll look into it.